# `MySQL GROUP BY is slower when using index

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, database-indexes

I'm running on an AWS m4.large (2 vCPUs, 8 GB ram) and I'm seeing a slightly surprising behaviour regarding MySQL and GROUPBY's. I have this test database:

```
CREATE TABLE demo (
  time INT,
  word VARCHAR(30),
  count INT
);
CREATE INDEX timeword_idx ON demo(time, word);
```

I insert 4,000,000 records with (uniformly) random words `"t%s" % random.randint(0, 30000)` and times `random.randint(0, 86400)`.

```
SELECT word, time, sum(count) FROM demo GROUP BY time, word;
3996922 rows in set (1 min 28.29 sec)

EXPLAIN SELECT word, time, sum(count) FROM demo GROUP BY time, word;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+---------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+---------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | demo  | index | NULL          | timeword_idx | 38      | NULL | 4002267 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+---------+-------+
```

and then I don't use the index:

```
SELECT word, time, sum(count) FROM demo IGNORE INDEX (timeword_idx) GROUP BY time, word;
3996922 rows in set (34.75 sec)

EXPLAIN SELECT word, time, sum(count) FROM demo IGNORE INDEX (timeword_idx) GROUP BY time, word;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | demo  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 4002267 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+---------------------------------+
```

As you can see by using the index the query takes 3 times more time. I'm not that surprised since by using the index the query might have to avoid reading the `time` and `word` columns but unfortunately by the index being so sparse it shouldn't gain much. On the contrary it turns a direct scan to a random access pattern when it comes to retrieving `count`.

I just would like to confirm that this is the reason and wonder if there's a "compact rule" on when and index will bring eventually worse performance when used for GROUP BY.

EDIT:

I followed Gordon Linoff's answer and used:

```
CREATE INDEX timeword_idx ON demo(time, word, count);
```

The "covering index" computes the results 10 times faster when compared with the full scan:

```
SELECT word, time, sum(count) FROM demo GROUP BY time, word;
3996922 rows in set (3.36 sec)

EXPLAIN SELECT word, time, sum(count) FROM demo GROUP BY time, word;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | demo  | index | NULL          | timeword_idx | 43      | NULL | 4002267 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

Very impressive!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a reasonably sized table, so the problem might be sequential access of the data or thrashing.  Using the index requires going through the index and then looking up the data in the data pages to get the `count`.

This can actually be worse than just reading the pages and doing a sort, because the pages are not read in order.  Sequential reads are considerably more optimized than random reads.  In the worst case, the page cache is full and the random reads require flushing pages.  If this happens, a single page might need to be read multiple times.  With only 4 million relatively small rows, thrashing is unlikely unless you are severely memory constrained.

If this interpretation is correct, then including `count` in the index should speed the query:

```
CREATE INDEX timeword_idx ON demo(time, word, count);
```

Comment: The other part of the "compact rule" about using an index would be about predicates (conditions) that limit the number of rows that need to be accessed, and whether MySQL can make effective use of an index range scan operation. If *every* row in the table has to be accessed, and if the query doesn't use a "covering" index, that necessitates lookups to pages in the underlying table. That's like accessing *every* block in the index once, and visiting *every* block in the table multiple times. If this is InnoDB table, without a primary key or unique index, the cluster key is internal rowID. +10

Comment: "covering index" gave amazing results. Updated the question to show them.

Answer (score 1):

From the manual page [How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html)

> Indexes are less important for queries on small tables, or big tables
>   where report queries process most or all of the rows. When a query
>   needs to access most of the rows, reading sequentially is faster than
>   working through an index. Sequential reads minimize disk seeks, even
>   if not all the rows are needed for the query.

As for tacking on more columns to create covering indexes (ones in which datapages are not accessed but all data is available in the index), be careful. They come at a cost. In your case, your index is getting wide anyway. But a careful balance is always needed.

As spencer alludes to, cardinality always play a role with ranges. For cardinality information, use the `show index from tblName` command. It is not a driving issue for your query, but useful in other settings. I should rephrase that: cardinality is very high for your table. So your index is deemed a hindrance for it in that query.

Comment: Given 30,000 values of word, and 86,400 values of time... that's 2,592,000,000 possible tuples. With a uniform distribution, with only 4,000,000 rows, there's very little likelihood for any duplicates. We'd expect a full scan through the data pages and a sort operation is going to be a lot faster. With a covering index for the query  (with word and time as leading columns), the GROUP BY operation would be optimized by using the index to avoid a sort. Adding the INT column to the index would add only 4 bytes per index entry. +10

Comment: I am not disputing that. It is already wide. Care should be taken not to turn every index into a covering one for junior devs.

Comment: "covering index" gave amazing results. Updated the question to show them.

Comment: They always do. They avoid the data pages!